# Calculating cosine-sine decomposition of a $4 \times 4$ unitary matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, unitary-matrices

I want to find the **cosine-sine** (CS) decomposition of the following $4 \times 4$ unitary matrix:

$$ U = \begin{pmatrix} U_{11}&U_{12}\\ U_{21}& U_{22}\end{pmatrix},$$

where

$$U_{11} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}, \qquad U_{12} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -1&1\\ -1& -1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$U_{21} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}, \qquad U_{22} = \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1&-1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I tried finding the singular value decomposition of $U_{11}$ and $U_{22}$ with $\mbox{SVD} (U_{11}) = (L_1, D_1, R_1)$ and $\mbox{SVD} (U_{22}) = (L_2, D_2, R_2)$.

I am not sure what should be the next step in order to find the CS decomposition of matrix $U$? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSD is not as easy to compute and a stable algorithm is not that straightforward, see [Paige, History and Generality of the CS Decomposition](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594904464) or [Van Loan, Computing the CS and the generalized singular value decompositions](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01389653). You can also google to find some freely available implementations, e.g. on GitHub.

The CSD will factorize the matrix $U$ with $U^T U=I$ as
$$
U:=
\begin{bmatrix}
U_{11} & U_{12}\\ U_{21} & U_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_{1} & 0\\ 0 & Z_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}\\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1}^T & 0\\ 0 & V_{2}^T
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $1\succeq \Sigma_{ij}\succeq -1$ and $Z_i,V_i$ are unitary. In addition, $\Sigma_{11}^T\Sigma_{11}+\Sigma_{12}^T\Sigma_{12}=\Sigma_{21}^T\Sigma_{21}+\Sigma_{22}^T\Sigma_{22}=I$.

In your case, $U_{11}=U_{22}=U_{21}$ and $U_{12}=-U_{21}$, from which you immediately follow that the choice $Z_1=Z_2=:Z$, $V_1=V_2=:V$, $\Sigma_{11}=\Sigma_{21}=\Sigma_{22}=-\Sigma_{12}=:\Sigma$ should work.

You can set $V=I$, obtain $Z$ from normalizing the columns of $U_{11}$ and $\Sigma$ from the reciprocal of these factors, i.e.

$$
Z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix},\qquad
\Sigma = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},\qquad
V=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
You will see that with this choice you have the properties of the factorization.